# Horizontal Panel not changing in Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, panel, window-resize, google-developer-tools

In chrome developer tools, In preferences, I can not change the panel layout into horizontal mode, if a change it, there are no changes,  why?

Comment: Probably because your devtools panel is too small.